# Dynamic ribbon office 365 using office.js add-in manifest xml

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, microsoft-teams

We want sign in / sign out ribbon using add-ins Manifest xml with react and office 365.

We use custom xml parts function of office.js but no result found

Comment: Please provide more details of what your are trying to accomplish. The manifest XML can only be used in the manifest. Custom XML parts are added (hidden) to the document, not the manifest.

Comment: We want to Sign in user by clicking on Login ribbon icon. After login there should be Sign out ribbon icon. We have manifest with custom control xsi:type button. When we upload manifest from office add-ins we can see Sign In ribbon under custom tab. Onclick we want manifest ribbon to be change with Sign out. We are using office.js to interact with office 365 excel. Please help me with this problem

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at this time to dynamically change button names or replace a button with another button. We are working on new APIs and manifest changes that will make this possible, but it cannot be done at present.